# html textarea mysql insert keep new lines for HTML and android

Tags: php, android, html, mysql

I have a mysql database in which user can insert a paragraph or two of text. If they click enter in either the wen entry or android entry I would like to keep that new line when I display the text on my website and in my android app.

My php for inserting into the db is:

```
<?php
error_log("starting code"); 
require_once('myConnectDB.inc.php');

        $u = $_POST['u'];
        $b = $_POST['b'];
        $n = $_POST['n'];

        //do some checks etc

        $db = new myConnectDB();


        $u = $db->real_escape_string($u);
        $n = $db->real_escape_string($n);
        $b = $db->real_escape_string($b);

        $query3 = "INSERT INTO tn (userID,beerID,note) VALUES ($u, '$b', '$n')";


        $result = $db->query($query3);

        $dbID = mysql_insert_id();

        echo $dbID;

?>
```

Comment: It should be saving new lines. Perhaps you need to convert them to `<br>` when you display?

Comment: How do I convert them to br? and would I do not think the br would be helpful in the android app...

Answer (score 0):

You need to **`urlencode`** the text of the android **`EditText`** before passing it to your PHP Service.

Say if you typed. **`Hello how are you ?`**  Only **`Hello`** will be interpreted and the remaining text gets truncated. You need to make use of this

```
EditText edt1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
String youredittextvalue = edt1.getText().toString().trim();
youredittextvalue = URLEncoder.encode(youredittextvalue, "utf-8");
```

Comment: I got that, right now I am working on getting text from the db to display correctly on the website with line breaks. Right now its taking the line breaks out.

Comment: The above code encodes the value and sends it to your PHP service, just store it raw(as it is) in the DB. When you display it , make use of urldecode.